# intelliJ code-inspection standalone using Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to run code inspection provided by [intelliJ-JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/code-inspection.html) using the java code.

Basically, can I import the intelliJ `engine` Or `factory` from plugins of a [community edition](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) to create a project on my own to inspect a piece of code?

I have tried seeking any such dependency but to no use. Creating a jar of plugins was another failed attempt.

***Edit*** - As answered by @Frankie and mentioned in the comments thereafter by me. Is there a way of not being dependent on IntelliJ as a whole but use just the `inspect` library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IntelliJ provides **code inspection from the command line**.

As [per the manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/2016.1/working-with-appcode-features-from-command-line.html) simply run:

```
<path-to-IntelliJ>\bin\inspect.sh <path-to-project> <path-to-inspection-profile>
```

From there it should be straightforward to apply to your desired case scenario.

Comment: How about not being dependent on IntelliJ as a whole but use just the `inspect` library?

Comment: @nullpointer I'd have to dig further but if I'd were to bet I'd say it wont comply with IntelliJ's TOS.